# i want to create a Tab bar using a single view application in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

i am new in iOS development
i want to create a Tab bar using single view application
so,i take a two view controller with xib and in app delegate i write these code but app is not running
Here also error is incompatible pointer type sending 'UiViewController' to 'UiView type'

```
-(void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item
{
    switch (item.tag)
    {
        case 1:
            if (view1 == nil)
            {
                self.view1=[[FirstViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil];
            }
            [self.view insertSubview:view1 aboveSubview:tabbar];
            break;
        case 2:
            if (view2 == nil)
            {
                self.view2=[[SecondViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
            }
            [self.view insertSubview:view2 aboveSubview:tabbar];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe I should have asked this before providing the answer below: why do you want a tab bar in a single view application?  A tab bar is for switching view controllers.

Comment: Sorry, previous comment was a little hasty.  Usually UITabBars are used to switch between controllers, but technically you can use them for other actions.  I edited my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you are getting is because you are trying to add a UIViewController as a subview to your view.  Generally a UITabBar is used to switch between view controllers, in which case you would want to use a segue or present the new view controller.  So if you really want to present a "FirstViewController" and "SecondViewController", you need to switch to those controllers, not add them as subviews.  If what you really want to do is switch between two different subviews within your single view, then you need to subclass UIView instead of UIViewController and use those subclasses where you are using FirstViewController and SecondViewController.

[Here's an example of something like this for a UIWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24255007/2715819)

Comment: i want a make tab bar with single view application not in tabbed application so please tell me any tutorial or any hint