# Can't set default button on tab bar in view controller

Tags: ios, swift

I have a `View Controller` with a `UITabBar` on the bottom. This tab bar performs a different function depending on which tab is selected. I would like to have one of the buttons selected when the `view controller` loads. I can't find a solution that doesn't involve a `tabbarviewcontroller`

Comment: Your question is unclear, please elaborate this.

Answer (score 0):

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITabBarDelegate {
@IBOutlet var tabBar : UITabBar
//In view controller declare a UITabBar as an Outlet
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tabBar.selectedItem = tabBar.items[0] as UITabBarItem;// here you 
    can load the default button option which you want to load                            
 }
func tabBar(tabBar: UITabBar!, didSelectItem item: UITabBarItem!) {
    var tabBarValue = 0;
    switch item.tag  {
    case 0:
        tabBarValue = // assign value 
        break
    case 1:
        tabBarValue = // assign value 
        break
    default:
       break
    }}
```

Pl. refer to the below url also, where they try to load different webview for the selected tab, [Use a UITabBar without UITabBarController to control a UIWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24221935/use-a-uitabbar-without-uitabbarcontroller-to-control-a-uiwebview)

Comment: For some reason this wasn't working me. However, I did find another way that did.

Answer (score 0):

This was the solution that worked out for me.

```
for i in tabBar.items as [UITabBarItem] {
        if i.tag == 0 {
            tabBar.selectedItem = i
        }
```