# UITabBar Event Handling

Tags: ios, swift, events

I'm new to iOS and Swift programming. I used to handle click events in other platforms.

I normally create IBAction for button objects. I wonder is it possible the same thing to handle touch events on TabBar items?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are not using UITabBarController:

[See Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24221935/use-a-uitabbar-without-uitabbarcontroller-to-control-a-uiwebview)

Otherwise storyboard handle segues for you:

[UITabBarController - tutorial (ioscreator.com)](http://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/tab-bar-controller-tutorial-ios8-swift)

But remember not to use TabBar for other purposes than navigation, user will be confused.

Comment: Thank you. It really helped me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

```
func tabBar(tabBar: UITabBar, didSelectItem item: UITabBarItem!) {
    if(item.tag == 0) {
       // first tab bar code
    }
    else if(item.tag == 1) {
      // second tab bar code
    }
}
```

Give tag on each tab tag from storyboard utility secton.

Comment: If you're using tags for something as simple as this, then you're doing something wrong. The other answer, which explains how to use segues, is far superior.

Answer (score 0):

Create a control view of the Main view that contains the TabBar and use UITabBarControllerDelegate functions to catch the event when the user tap on one of the items tabs

```
class TabBarController:  UITabBarController,   UITabBarControllerDelegate {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.delegate = self
    }

    // UITabBarControllerDelegate
    func tabBarController(tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelectViewController viewController: UIViewController) {
        if let navBar = viewController as? NaughtyNavigationController {
            navBar.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
        }
    }
}
```